# Download data from firebase Firestore to flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I am using Firestore as a database for a Chat in one part of the application that I am building. I have a collection on my Firestore that looks like this:

```
messages(collection)
    userId
        userId-otherUserId(sub-collection)
            randomId
            content : String, 
            timestamp : Date
            ...
```

and I would like to retrieve firstly all of the userIs-otherUserId in a ListView and then to retrieve the lastMessage by retrieving the last randomId(and in that randomId the last message is the last element with key 'content') and I would like it to look something like this.

[Prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npXlH.png)

where the Loading represents last message but the name and profilePicture I can get from my API.

The pictures of my Firestore database:

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEqtK.png)

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqM5d.png)

[Third Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66sVY.png)

Is there any chance that I could save the name and Profile picture on the database in the userId-otherUserId(collection)?

The code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:disby_app/const.dart';
import 'package:disby_app/data/request_model.dart';
import 'package:disby_app/global_widgets/loading_indicator.dart';
import 'package:disby_app/main_screens/main_chat_and_request_screens/chat.dart';
import 'package:disby_app/main_screens/main_chat_and_request_screens/profile_details_screen.dart';
import 'package:disby_app/public/keys.dart';
import 'package:disby_app/services/json_requests.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_translate/flutter_translate.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '../../global_widgets/chat_and_requests_placeholder.dart';

class MainChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainChatScreenState createState() => _MainChatScreenState();
}

class _MainChatScreenState extends State<MainChatScreen> {
  bool _areThereChats = false;
  bool _isLoading = true;
  String groupChatId;

  String userId = '1';

  List<String> listOfLastMessages = [];
  List<String> listOfIds = [];

  List<ArrayOfRequestsModel> arrayOfRequests = [];
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey();

  Future readLocal() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    userId = prefs.getString(kUserId) ?? '';
    print(userId);
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<void> _getRequests() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final userId = prefs.getString(kUserId);
    try {
      await Dio().post(baseUrl + acceptedUsers + "/" + userId).then((snapshot) {
        print(snapshot);
        final Map<String, dynamic> response = snapshot.data;
        print(response);
        if (response['response'] == 'success') {
          List<dynamic> arrayFromServer = response['acceptedUsers'];
          if (arrayFromServer.isNotEmpty) {
            arrayFromServer.forEach((userData) {
              arrayOfRequests.add(ArrayOfRequestsModel.fromJson(userData));
              listOfIds.add(userData['userId']);
              print(userData['userId']);
            });
            _areThereChats = true;
            _isLoading = false;
            getMessages(userId);
          } else {
            _areThereChats = false;
            _isLoading = false;
          }
          setState(() {});
        } else {
          _areThereChats = false;
          _isLoading = false;
          setState(() {});
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  getMessages(String userId) {
    int i = 0;
    print(listOfIds.length);
    print(listOfIds);
    listOfIds.forEach((element) {
      Firestore.instance
          .collection('messages')
          .document('$userId')
          .collection('$userId-$element')
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
          .limit(3)
          .getDocuments()
          .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.documents[0].data['content']);
        snapshot.documents.forEach((f) {
          print(f.data['content']);
          listOfLastMessages.add(f.data['content']);
          setState(() {});
          i++;
        });
        if (i == listOfIds.length) {
          setState(() {});
          print(listOfLastMessages);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    readLocal();
    _getRequests();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          //   child: (userId != '1')
          //       ? StreamBuilder(
          //           stream: Firestore.instance
          //               .collection('messages')
          //               .document('5ef4d83175b07cf074525c08')
          //               .snapshots(),
          //           builder: (context, snapshot) {
          //             // if (snapshot.hasData) {
          //             if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          //               return Center(
          //                 child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          //                   valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(themeColor),
          //                 ),
          //               );
          //             } else {
          //               return Container(
          //                 width: 100,
          //                 height: 200,
          //                 child: ListView.builder(
          //                   padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          //                   itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
          //                       buildItem(context, snapshot.data.documents),
          //                   itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
          //                 ),
          //               );
          //             }
          //           },
          //         )
          //       : LoadingIndicator(
          //           loading: _isLoading,
          //         ),
          // ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              (_isLoading == false)
                  ? (_areThereChats == true)
                      ? Container(
                          child: AnimatedList(
                            key: _listKey,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            initialItemCount: arrayOfRequests.length,
                            itemBuilder:
                                (BuildContext context, index, animation) {
                              return _buildItem(context, arrayOfRequests[index],
                                  animation, index);
                            },
                          ),
                        )
                      : ChatAndRequestPlaceholder(
                          text: translate('when_someone_sends_you_a_request'))
                  : LoadingIndicator(
                      loading: _isLoading,
                    ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    if (document['id'] == userId) {
      return Container();
    } else {
      return Container(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'Nickname: ${document['content']}',
                          style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor),
                        ),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'About me: ${document['content'] ?? 'Not available'}',
                          style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor),
                        ),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Chat(
                  peerId: document.documentID,
                  peerAvatar: document['photoUrl'],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          color: greyColor2,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25.0, 10.0, 25.0, 10.0),
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
      );
    }
  }

  _buildItem(BuildContext context, ArrayOfRequestsModel arrayOfSentRequests,
      Animation animation, int index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print(arrayOfSentRequests.profilePictureUrl);
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Chat(
              peerId: arrayOfSentRequests.userId,
              peerAvatar: arrayOfSentRequests.profilePictureUrl,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 82,
        child: ScaleTransition(
          scale: animation,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.07),
                    offset: Offset(0, 5),
                    blurRadius: 11,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 78,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      height: double.infinity,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ProfileDetailsScreen(),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(width: 24),
                            ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                              child: Image(
                                image: NetworkImage(
                                  arrayOfSentRequests.profilePictureUrl,
                                ),
                                width: 48,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 10),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            arrayOfSentRequests.nameAndSurname,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                              fontSize: 18,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            '11/11/2020', //arrayOfSentRequests.nameAndSurname
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.grey,
                                              fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                              fontSize: 15,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      child: Text(
                                        // (arrayOfSentRequests.lastMessage !=
                                        //         null)
                                        //     ? arrayOfSentRequests.lastMessage
                                        //     : 'Loading..',
                                        (listOfLastMessages.isNotEmpty)
                                            ? listOfLastMessages[index]
                                                .toString()
                                            : 'Loading...',
                                        maxLines: 2,
                                        softWrap: true,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black54,
                                          fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 10),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                        size: 22,
                        color: Colors.black54,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Bilal Drndo, welcome to Stack Overflow, what you described is indeed quite possible to do, however, you are encouraged to try it out for yourself first, instead of asking for a fully built solution. So, what have you tried so far on this case? Can you share the code that you have already started to implement in order to connect to firestore? Also, to you secondary question, from a architecture perspective, I would store the userName in the same `userId-otherUserId` collection and another field with a URL of the picture in google cloud storage, which is where I would store the picture.

Comment: Thank You for your response, I will update the code now. The problem with your solution is that I have already stored the pictures on mongodb and I don't want to duplicate the process. I would like to save only the pictureUrl if possible on Firebase, and that is why I am asking for an alternative solution.

Comment: Same idea, if you have the pictureUrl you can store it in any collection that you'd like.